# What is the best way to truncate the beginning of a file in C?

Tags: c

There are many similar questions, but nothing that answers this specifically after googling around quite a bit.  Here goes:

Say we have a file (could be binary, and much bigger too):

> abcdefghijklmnopqrztuvwxyz

what is the best way in C to "move" a right most portion of this file to the left, truncating the beginning of the file.. so, for example, "front truncating" 7 bytes would change the file on disk to be:

> hijklmnopqrztuvwxyz

I must avoid temporary files, and would prefer not to use a large buffer to read the whole file into memory.  One possible method I thought of is to use fopen with "rb+" flag, and constantly fseek back and forth reading and writing to copy bytes starting from offset to the beginning, then setEndOfFile to truncate at the end.  That seems to be a lot of seeking (possibly inefficient).

Another way would be to fopen the same file twice, and use fgetc and fputc with the respective file pointers.  Is this even possible?

If there are other ways, I'd love to read all of them.

Comment: I ended up opening the file twice (with two FILE pointers).  This was very fast (~2mb in blink of an eye; didn't benchmark).  I used ftruncate() with fileno() and ftell().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use an enormous buffer size, and the kernel is going to be doing the hard work for you, but yes, reading a buffer full from up the file and writing nearer the beginning is the way to do it if you can't afford to do the simpler job of create a new file, copy what you want into that file, and then copy the new (temporary) file over the old one.  I wouldn't rule out the possibility that the approach of copying what you want to a new file and then either moving the new file in place of the old or copying the new over the old will be faster than the shuffling process you describe.  If the number of bytes to be removed was a disk block size, rather than 7 bytes, the situation might be different, but probably not.  The only disadvantage is that the copying approach requires more intermediate disk space.

Your outline approach will require the use of `truncate()` or `ftruncate()` to shorten the file to the proper length, assuming you are on a POSIX system.  If you don't have `truncate()`, then you will need to do the copying.

Note that opening the file twice will work OK if you are careful not to clobber the file when opening for writing - using `"r+b"` mode with `fopen()`, or avoiding `O_TRUNC` with `open()`.

Comment: thank you for a great response! the size of the blocks to move may be substantial (on the order of megabytes).  My concern about avoiding temporary files is not with space, but rather the persistence of sensitive data.  I want to limit the physical storage of bytes to one place on disk (although the copy is deleted, the bytes may still be present).

BTW, I am on linux.  Will the kernel do the hard work if I'm seeking back and forth every byte, or what would an optimal buffer be if not? I'm wondering if the last option would result in the same thing physically happening.

Comment: If you do single byte read and write operations, you will be making something (standard I/O or the kernel - or perhaps both) do a lot of work.  Working in kilobyte sized chunks (say 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 KiB chunks) would be more efficient, without stressing all but the most impoverished of environments.  The kernel will deal with alignments etc for you - fortunately.

Answer (score 6):

You could [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/mmap) the file into memory and then memmove the contents. You would have to truncate the file separately.

Comment: So, would the steps be:
1) mmap
2) memmove
3) un-mmap (does this exist?)
4) truncate
?

Comment: @snapfractalpop [related example here](http://pastebin.com/s1vSCvxA). This solution has potential to be really fast, but file size is limited by address space size. You won't be able to truncate big(>4GB) files on 32bit systems.

Comment: @Banthar: it's worse than that: you need a contiguous part of your process's address space that's big enough.  That could be a lot less than 4GB, depending on fragmentation and other memory allocations.

Comment: @Joe You could always do it in slices, of course, just as long as you're careful at the overlaps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, since Kernel 3.15 you can use

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int fallocate(int fd, int mode, off_t offset, off_t len);
```

with the `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE`  flag.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man2/fallocate.2.html

Note that not all file systems support it but most modern ones such as ext4 and xfs do.